# Symfony - extension already registered

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Symfony version is 3.3, PHP is 7.1

Hi, I am dealing with weird problem and I have no idea why it happens. When I run my app on localhost everything work fine, but when I run it on remote server it doesn't work even while using *app_dev.php*. Live version: http://task.shaelex2.ayz.pl/web/app_dev.php/

The error is:

```
Unable to register extension "AppBundle\Service\MailerService" as it is already registered.
```

*services.yml*

```
CoreService:
    class: AppBundle\Service\CoreService
    arguments:
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            - "@swiftmailer.mailer.default"
            - "@twig"
     public: true


MailSender:
    class: AppBundle\Service\MailerService
    arguments:
            - "@swiftmailer.mailer.default"
            - "@twig"
    public: true
```

MailerService.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_Message;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle;

class MailerService extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $mailer;
    public function __construct(Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function sendMail($address, $adverts)
    {
        $message = new Swift_Message('Adverts');
        $message->setFrom("xxx");
        $message->setTo($address);
        $message->setBody(
            $this->twig->render(':email:email.html.twig', array('emails' => $adverts)),
            'text/html');
        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

*CoreService.php*

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\Advert;
use AppBundle\Entity\Logs;
use AppBundle\Entity\UserSettings;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Swift_Mailer;

class CoreService
{
    protected $em;
    protected $mailer;
    protected $twig;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig_Environment $twig) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function fetch() {
        print ("fetching\n");
        $links = $this->em->getRepository(UserSettings::class)->findAll();
        foreach ($links as $link) {
            $driver = $link->getPortal();
            print ($driver);
            $site = $link->getDeepLink();
            $scraper1 = new Scraper(new AdvertScrapeDriver($driver), $site);
            $run = $scraper1->scrapeAdverts($this->em);
            $logs = new Logs($driver, $site);
            $this->em->persist($logs);
        }
        print("emailing\n");
        $emails = $this->em
            ->getRepository(Advert::class)
            ->findBy(array('sent' => '0'));
        foreach ($emails as $object) {
            /* $object Advert */
            $object->setSent(1);
            $this->em->persist($object);
        }
        $logs = new Logs("email", "xxx");
        $this->em->persist($logs);
        $this->em->flush();
        print("logs done\n");
        $mails = new MailerService($this->mailer, $this->twig);
        $mails->sendMail("xxx", $emails);
        print("sent emails\n");
        return $emails;

    }
    public function test(){
        print("testuje");
        $emails = $this->em
            ->getRepository(Advert::class)
            ->findBy(array('sent' => '0'));
        $mails = new MailerService($this->mailer, $this->twig);
        $mails->sendMail("xxx", $emails);
    }
}
```

And the route which use CoreService

```
    /**
     * @Route("/debug/fetch", name="debug_fetch")
     */
    public function debugFetch(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig_Environment $twig) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $sg = new CoreService($em, $mailer, $twig);
        $emails = $sg->fetch();
        return $this->render('email/email.html.twig', array(
            'emails' => $emails,
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are using [default](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/service_container.html#service-container-services-load-example) symfony configuration, and your twig extension already loaded by symfony.

Read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service) documentation

> Next, register your class as a service and tag it with twig.extension.
>   If you're using the default services.yml configuration, you're done!
>   Symfony will automatically know about your new service and add the
>   tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using any package which already registered with "MailerService"
Try to use any other name of class.